# What happens when declaring an additional index on the primary key in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, primary-key

I have a multi-part question:

My journey began when I was trying to figure out if I can have descending/ascending primary keys in Oracle SQL.

There doesn't seem to be syntax along the lines of `CREATE TABLE MYTAB (ID INT PRIMARY KEY DESC);` or `CREATE TABLE MYTAB (ID INT, CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY(ID DESC));`

Later I learned Oracle implicitly creates an index for the primary key to help enforce its constraints. I figured I could create an index for it, and make the index descending.

`CREATE INDEX MYIND ON MYTAB (ID DESC);`

This worked, when I did a query to see which indices existed I got this:

```
> SELECT INDEX_NAME FROM USER_INDEXES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MYTAB';

INDEX_NAME
------------------------------
SYS_C0011939
MYIND
```

I see that the implicitly created index is there as well as my own index... I tried to see if I could get rid of the implicitly created index by creating the index for the primary key during the table create:

```
 CREATE TABLE MYTAB (ID INT PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX (CREATE INDEX MYIND ON MYTAB (ID ASC)));
```

This worked:

```
> SELECT INDEX_NAME FROM USER_INDEXES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MYTAB';

INDEX_NAME
------------------------------
MYIND
```

Interestingly, using DESC as the index direction gives me the following error:

`Specified index cannot be used to enforce the constraint.`

---

So my questions are:

1. Does this mean DESCENDING primary keys are not possible in Oracle SQL?
2. If so, why does DESC disallow primary key constraints from being enforced?
3. What exactly is the behavior/effect of creating an index separately as in my first example? The DESC worked there... What happens when a primary key has two indices on it? Does it function the same way another DB allows for DESC as part of the primary key specification?

Comment: Why do you think you need a DESC index?

Comment: I'm writing a tool that will generate statements for a bunch of different databases  - I'm looking into allowing the user to specify ascending/descending options, and seeing how each different db implementation handles ascending/descending indices. It seems like Oracle has no need for it like you said

Answer (score 1):

Oracle creates indexes as double-linked lists, so that every index can be traversed in ascending OR descending order when needed.

For **multi-column** indexes, however, you can add the `DESC` keyword to have one or more columns stored in descending order with respect to the other columns.

This has limited usefulness and is not often used - but it can be useful when you are creating an index specifically to support a particular `ORDER BY` clause in a particular query where some (but not all) columns are sorted in descending order.